# Monotouch - tranistioning to xCode 4 - XIBs not working

Tags: c#, xcode, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a solution with XIBs created in IB 3.x. When I edit them in xCode 4 and save the changes, my Xib files are all messed up and do not show anything - just blank screens.

Perhaps the project did not upgrade correctly?
If anyone has any ideas, please let me know asap - I can't edit any of the XIBs!

Setup:
1. I double checked that MT and MD are up to date.
2. Compiling for ios 4.x
3. The problem is 100% reproducible, given my setup and solution

Here are the before and after files. Following them are the exact steps I used to produce the problem.

Becuase of the 5K limit, I can't post the entire files but the jist is that the new Xcode 4 files have full getters and setters.

**** ORIGINAL XCode 3.x CODE:

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//  <autogenerated>
//      This code was generated by a tool.
//      Mono Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.1
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if 
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </autogenerated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace iPhoneSolution 
{
    // Base type probably should be MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController or subclass
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("NewTaskView")]
    public partial class NewTaskView {

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView __mt_view;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton __mt_cmdAddRecipient;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton __mt_cmdPickDateTime;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView __mt_txtDescription;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField __mt_txtDueDat;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField __mt_txtName;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView __mt_txtRecipients;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton __mt_cmdDoneDescription;

    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton __mt_cmdSend;

    #pragma warning disable 0169
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("view")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView view {
        get {
            this.__mt_view = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView)(this.GetNativeField("view")));
            return this.__mt_view;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_view = value;
            this.SetNativeField("view", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("cmdAddRecipient")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdAddRecipient {
        get {
            this.__mt_cmdAddRecipient = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton)(this.GetNativeField("cmdAddRecipient")));
            return this.__mt_cmdAddRecipient;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_cmdAddRecipient = value;
            this.SetNativeField("cmdAddRecipient", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("cmdPickDateTime")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdPickDateTime {
        get {
            this.__mt_cmdPickDateTime = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton)(this.GetNativeField("cmdPickDateTime")));
            return this.__mt_cmdPickDateTime;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_cmdPickDateTime = value;
            this.SetNativeField("cmdPickDateTime", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("txtDescription")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView txtDescription {
        get {
            this.__mt_txtDescription = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView)(this.GetNativeField("txtDescription")));
            return this.__mt_txtDescription;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_txtDescription = value;
            this.SetNativeField("txtDescription", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("txtDueDat")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField txtDueDat {
        get {
            this.__mt_txtDueDat = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField)(this.GetNativeField("txtDueDat")));
            return this.__mt_txtDueDat;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_txtDueDat = value;
            this.SetNativeField("txtDueDat", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("txtName")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField txtName {
        get {
            this.__mt_txtName = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField)(this.GetNativeField("txtName")));
            return this.__mt_txtName;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_txtName = value;
            this.SetNativeField("txtName", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("txtRecipients")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView txtRecipients {
        get {
            this.__mt_txtRecipients = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView)(this.GetNativeField("txtRecipients")));
            return this.__mt_txtRecipients;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_txtRecipients = value;
            this.SetNativeField("txtRecipients", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("cmdDoneDescription")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdDoneDescription {
        get {
            this.__mt_cmdDoneDescription = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton)(this.GetNativeField("cmdDoneDescription")));
            return this.__mt_cmdDoneDescription;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_cmdDoneDescription = value;
            this.SetNativeField("cmdDoneDescription", value);
        }
    }

    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("cmdSend")]
    private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdSend {
        get {
            this.__mt_cmdSend = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton)(this.GetNativeField("cmdSend")));
            return this.__mt_cmdSend;
        }
        set {
            this.__mt_cmdSend = value;
            this.SetNativeField("cmdSend", value);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

After modifying the xib in xCode 4:

```
// WARNING
//
// This file has been generated automatically by MonoDevelop to store outlets and
// actions made in the Xcode designer. If it is removed, they will be lost.
// Manual changes to this file may not be handled correctly.
//
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

namespace iPhoneSolution
{
    [Register ("NewTaskView")]
    partial class NewTaskView
    {
        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView view { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdAddRecipient { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdPickDateTime { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView txtDescription { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField txtDueDat { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField txtName { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextView txtRecipients { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdDoneDescription { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdSend { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton cmdDoSomething { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Here are the steps I used to reproduce it:

1. Run the app and verify that the View in question displays properly
2. double click the nib file to open it in xCode 4
3. Drag and drop a round rect button onto the View
4. Select Save "xxxx"
5. Run the app in Debug|iPhoneSimulator. It is displaying the view.
6. stop the app
7. double click the sib to open it in xCode 4.
8. Control-Drag from the button to the .h
9. Create an outlet named cmdDosomething
10. Close and save the file.
11. Set breakpoints at the beginning of ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear for the view.
12. Restart the application
13. Click on the Tab that displays the view. ViewDidAppear is hit. ViewDidLoad is NOT hit. The view does **NOT** appear, only a blank white area above the tab bar
14. Click randomly on the tabs. All other views appear fine. ViewDidAppear is called normally on the view in question.

I would really appreciate an pointers or ideas.
Thanks a million
WCM

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same issue and was able to figure out the cause and solution:

My views that were created prior to 2.8 had an outlet for the View called view. When I opened the header file, I discovered that XCode was complaining that declaration for the view was a duplicate name.

Since this seemed like it could be the source of the problem, I took the following steps:

1) Deleted the view outlet in the file owner's list of outlets

2) Manually removed the two references to view in the header file

3) Linked the View outlet in the file owner's list of outlets directly to the view (I did not drag the connection to the header file, I dragged it to the view that is on left-hand side of the designer area). If you forget to do this step, you will receive a runtime error about the nib being loaded but the view outlet not being sent.

Hopefully this will help you resolve the issue.

I forgot to mention: the designer file is correct; MT changed the way that the outlets are identified in the designer file.

Comment: This solution is correct - simply remove the redundant view outlet, which would have originally been created to work around limitations in Interface Builder 3, but conflicts with the new simplified designer code. MonoDevelop 2.8.2 will remove it automatically. You can find a full explanation at http://support.xamarin.com/customer/portal/questions/40506-view-outlet-was-not-set-when-using-xcode-4